# Getting the most out of one night in LAX

Tags: transit, los-angeles

I am travelling to Japan for studies, and my flight has a layover in LAX for the night. I will arrive at LAX at 5 p.m. and have to be back at the airport by 10 a.m. the next day (as the flight leaves at 1 p.m. to Japan).

I will be staying in a an inn near the Airport (La Quinta Inn and Suites LAX). I don't have a driver's license so I can't rent a car, although maybe my travel partner can but I am not sure. I know it's too much to ask but I'd like to do at least one thing that is cool in LA.

Comment: It's not far from Venice Beach

Comment: This question is probably too open-ended to be a good fit for this site.  See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), in particular "and it's not about … asking for the 'best' thing to do (or similarly subjective questioning)."

Comment: Almost certainly this will get closed as subjective and broad, but you could join the [chat] and ask us.  I recommend an uber to Venice Beach, you get the area, the people, the beach and water, and a view.

Comment: I never thought about an Uber, good thinking mate I think I might do that.

Comment: My recommendation, take an Uber to Santa Monica Pier.